# R histogram and descriptive stats on a set of strings

Tags: string, r, statistics

I have a vector of strings, with 50 entries where there are only about 7 distinct strings. I would like to plot the distinct strings on the X-axis and their count on the Y-axis and display some descriptive statistics. I would like this to be a histogram, but I get an error from R saying that it does not accept character data.

Which R methods can I use to do this efficiently? I guess what I really need to do is group these 7 distinct items and then get a count of each item, but how do I group in R?

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Give some sample data and what you've tried.  You're not a complete rookie. You should know this.

Answer (score 9):

plot the output of `table` on the object. This will count the occurences of each unique value

```
 set.seed(1)
 d <- sample(letters[1:7], 50, replace = TRUE)
 plot(table(d))

 # or
 barplot(table(d))
```

Comment: use barplot() to achieve something like the "histogram" part of the question. But apparently plot.table does a mosaic plot. Didn't know that!

Comment: `barplot` does the job nicely!